# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer Preferences in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting an error on this line

```
slider.Value = Preferences.Get("sl", 3/8)
```

I don't understand what is the issue? This preference should return a double and as I understand slider.value expects a double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences.Get uses the 2nd argument to decide how to cast the result.  3/8 is an `int` divided by an `int`, so it will return an `int`.  That means it will try to cast the string that it has stored as an int, which is failing

```
slider.Value = Preferences.Get("sl", 3/8);
```

instead, try this

```
slider.Value = Preferences.Get("sl", 3.0/8);
```

this will divide a `double` by an `int`, returning a `double`

or just this

```
slider.Value = Preferences.Get("sl", 0.0375);
```